# How can I emulate End Process Tree in C#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, batch-file

We have a web application that has to launch other processes.  Typically these processes are batch files that launch a series of other processes.  Sometimes we need to kill a batch file process that is running and to do that we need to kill it and its children.

What is the best way to go about this in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but posting here in case someone else also looking for the answer

1. To run a batch file in admin mode :
   [how to use c# run batch file as Administrator to install windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321981/how-to-use-c-sharp-run-batch-file-as-administrator-to-install-windows-services)
2. To programmatically kill process tree :
   [Kill process tree programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901679/kill-process-tree-programmatically-in-c-sharp)

combining them should do the job.

hope it helps.

Comment: You can also write a monitor that checks if the batch is not responding , a not-responding checker and then programatically kill it