# Working example of CreateJobObject/SetInformationJobObject pinvoke in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-4.0, pinvoke

I'm struggling to put together a working example of pinvoke'ing CreateJobObject and SetInformationJobObject.  Through various google searches (including Russian and Chinese posts!)  I've cobbled together the following code.  I think the definition of JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION changes based on platform (32/64-bit).  The CreateJobObject/AssignProcessToJobObject *seems* to work.  SetInformationJobObject fails - either with error 24 or 87.

```
Process myProcess // POPULATED SOMEWHERE ELSE

// Create Job & assign this process and another process to the job
IntPtr jobHandle = CreateJobObject( null , null );
AssignProcessToJobObject( jobHandle , myProcess.Handle );
AssignProcessToJobObject( jobHandle , Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle );

// Ensure that killing one process kills the others                
JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION limits = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION();
limits.LimitFlags = (short)LimitFlags.JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
IntPtr pointerToJobLimitInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( Marshal.SizeOf( limits ) );
Marshal.StructureToPtr( limits , pointerToJobLimitInfo , false );   
SetInformationJobObject( job , JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS.JobObjectBasicLimitInformation , pionterToJobLimitInfo ,  ( uint )Marshal.SizeOf( limits ) )
...


        [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" , EntryPoint = "CreateJobObjectW" , CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject( SecurityAttributes JobAttributes , string lpName );

        public class SecurityAttributes
        {

            public int nLength; //Useless field = 0
            public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor; //хз))
            public bool bInheritHandle; //Возможность наследования

            public SecurityAttributes()
            {
                this.bInheritHandle = true;
                this.nLength = 0;
                this.pSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
        static extern bool SetInformationJobObject( IntPtr hJob , JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS JobObjectInfoClass , IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo , uint cbJobObjectInfoLength );

        public enum JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS
        {
            JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7 ,
            JobObjectBasicLimitInformation = 2 ,
            JobObjectBasicUIRestrictions = 4 ,
            JobObjectEndOfJobTimeInformation = 6 ,
            JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation = 9 ,
            JobObjectSecurityLimitInformation = 5
        }


        [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
        struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            public Int64 PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
            public Int64 PerJobUserTimeLimit;
            public Int16 LimitFlags;
            public UIntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
            public UIntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
            public Int16 ActiveProcessLimit;
            public Int64 Affinity;
            public Int16 PriorityClass;
            public Int16 SchedulingClass;
        }

        public enum LimitFlags
        {
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_ACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000008 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_AFFINITY = 0x00000010 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK = 0x00000800 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_DIE_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION = 0x00000400 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY = 0x00000200 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME = 0x00000004 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE = 0x00002000 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PRESERVE_JOB_TIME = 0x00000040 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY = 0x00000100 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_TIME = 0x00000002 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SCHEDULING_CLASS = 0x00000080 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK = 0x00001000 ,
            JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_WORKINGSET = 0x00000001
        }


        [DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
        [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
        static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject( IntPtr hJob , IntPtr hProcess );

        [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }
```

Comment: [JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147(v=vs.85).aspx) defines `LimitFlags`, `PriorityClass` and `SchedulingClass` to be `DWORD`s, which translates to `Int32`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This can be little bit late, but still.

I tried all of the examples here, but no one was working for me in 32 and 64 bit mode simultaneously. Finally, I was required to examine all the signatures myself and create corresponding PInvoke routines. I think, somebody else could find this helpful.

**Disclaimer: the solution is based on [Matt Howells' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657392/607959).**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace JobManagement
{
    public class Job : IDisposable
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr a, string lpName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JobObjectInfoType infoType, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, UInt32 cbJobObjectInfoLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr job, IntPtr process);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        private IntPtr handle;
        private bool disposed;

        public Job()
        {
            handle = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, null);

            var info = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
            {
                LimitFlags = 0x2000
            };

            var extendedInfo = new JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
            {
                BasicLimitInformation = info
            };

            int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
            IntPtr extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

            if (!SetInformationJobObject(handle, JobObjectInfoType.ExtendedLimitInformation, extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to set information.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing) { }

            Close();
            disposed = true;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public bool AddProcess(IntPtr processHandle)
        {
            return AssignProcessToJobObject(handle, processHandle);
        }

        public bool AddProcess(int processId)
        {
            return AddProcess(Process.GetProcessById(processId).Handle);
        }

    }

    #region Helper classes

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct IO_COUNTERS
    {
        public UInt64 ReadOperationCount;
        public UInt64 WriteOperationCount;
        public UInt64 OtherOperationCount;
        public UInt64 ReadTransferCount;
        public UInt64 WriteTransferCount;
        public UInt64 OtherTransferCount;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
    {
        public Int64 PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
        public Int64 PerJobUserTimeLimit;
        public UInt32 LimitFlags;
        public UIntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
        public UIntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
        public UInt32 ActiveProcessLimit;
        public UIntPtr Affinity;
        public UInt32 PriorityClass;
        public UInt32 SchedulingClass;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public UInt32 nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public Int32 bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
    {
        public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
        public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
        public UIntPtr ProcessMemoryLimit;
        public UIntPtr JobMemoryLimit;
        public UIntPtr PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
        public UIntPtr PeakJobMemoryUsed;
    }

    public enum JobObjectInfoType
    {
        AssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7,
        BasicLimitInformation = 2,
        BasicUIRestrictions = 4,
        EndOfJobTimeInformation = 6,
        ExtendedLimitInformation = 9,
        SecurityLimitInformation = 5,
        GroupInformation = 11
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: `Win32.CloseHandle(handle);` is imported from kernel32.dll, yes? Your code (unmodified aside from a conversion to VB.NET) wouldn't compile for me without the external reference, though I am using .NET 2.0. I notice both your and Matt's answers don't import it explicitly, and I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are absolutely right. Win32 is a custom class, which is not here.

Comment: I used [this for Win32.CloseHandle](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.closehandle). I still couldn't get this to work, and the trick was to add an app.manifest [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9507862/197911). Just note that this won't work in the VS debugger. You have to launch the parent process on its own.

Comment: Alexander, you are a life saver! I used Matt's example and had some trouble (presumably because it's x64), your update did the trick! I'm using the JobObject to spawn a process from a Windows Service and it's working great.

Comment: Great  tjamls Alexander and Mas! Adding instead of Win32.CloseHandle worked

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

did the trick.

Comment: Doesn't `Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false)` leave the unmanaged memory allocated to the `extendedInfoPtr`? Is there a memory leak if `DestroyStructure` is not called?

Comment: instead of using win32.Close handle use a pinvoke
` public void Close()
        {
            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);`

Comment: The DWORD mappings are wrong, should be uint and not short. Update: JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION is broken in many places. Beware.

Comment: @AdamPlocher how did you guys get this to work? The Win32 class is not present.

Comment: @It'satrap adding a class called Win32 with the following should fix it:          `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);` (note, that's 3 lines of code, line 1: attribute, line2: other attrib, line 3 static extern)

Comment: @It'satrap also take a look at Andrew's answer below.  I believe the manifest file is needed now-a-days.  Plus he has my code in a more readable format (apparently the second attrib isn't needed)

Comment: @AdamPlocher Is it possible to set limit falg to more than 1 value. I see that we can either kill all processes or limit the maximum Ram used or so on. How can we put more than 1 restriction on the job object

Comment: Can this be used in .NET Core?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks to you and Matt.

Comment: @Keith I believe `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` is the problem. I think Marshal.FreeHGlobal() should be called after using the structure.

Answer (score 9):

Improving on Alexander's answer, here's a version that uses a `SafeHandle`. This is a `CriticalFinalizerObject` that makes working with handles much safer. .NET APIs (such as the `Process` class) always use `SafeHandle`s with P/Invoke instead of `IntPtr`s.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

public sealed class ChildProcessManager : IDisposable
{
    private SafeJobHandle? _handle;
    private bool _disposed;

    public ChildProcessManager()
    {
        _handle = new SafeJobHandle(CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, null));

        var info = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            LimitFlags = 0x2000
        };

        var extendedInfo = new JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            BasicLimitInformation = info
        };

        var length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
        var extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

        if (!SetInformationJobObject(_handle, JobObjectInfoType.ExtendedLimitInformation, extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to set information", new Win32Exception());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed) return;

        _handle?.Dispose();
        _handle = null;
        _disposed = true;
    }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(_handle))]
    private void ValidateDisposed()
    {
        ObjectDisposedException.ThrowIf(_disposed || _handle is null, this);
    }

    public void AddProcess(SafeProcessHandle processHandle)
    {
        ValidateDisposed();
        if (!AssignProcessToJobObject(_handle, processHandle))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to add the process");
        }
    }

    public void AddProcess(Process process)
    {
        AddProcess(process.SafeHandle);
    }

    public void AddProcess(int processId)
    {
        using var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        AddProcess(process);
    }

    private sealed class SafeJobHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public SafeJobHandle(IntPtr handle) : base(true)
        {
            SetHandle(handle);
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(handle);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr a, string? lpName);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(SafeJobHandle hJob, JobObjectInfoType infoType, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, uint cbJobObjectInfoLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(SafeJobHandle job, SafeProcessHandle process);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct IO_COUNTERS
    {
        public ulong ReadOperationCount;
        public ulong WriteOperationCount;
        public ulong OtherOperationCount;
        public ulong ReadTransferCount;
        public ulong WriteTransferCount;
        public ulong OtherTransferCount;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
    {
        public long PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
        public long PerJobUserTimeLimit;
        public uint LimitFlags;
        public UIntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
        public UIntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
        public uint ActiveProcessLimit;
        public UIntPtr Affinity;
        public uint PriorityClass;
        public uint SchedulingClass;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public uint nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
    {
        public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
        public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
        public UIntPtr ProcessMemoryLimit;
        public UIntPtr JobMemoryLimit;
        public UIntPtr PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
        public UIntPtr PeakJobMemoryUsed;
    }

    private enum JobObjectInfoType
    {
        AssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7,
        BasicLimitInformation = 2,
        BasicUIRestrictions = 4,
        EndOfJobTimeInformation = 6,
        ExtendedLimitInformation = 9,
        SecurityLimitInformation = 5,
        GroupInformation = 11
    }
}
```

Comment: This is giving compilation error at `_handle.Dispose()`

Answer (score 5):

To summarize, the signatures posed by Alexander Yezutov work under both x86 and x64. Matt Howells signatures use a number of UInt32's when UIntPtr should be used instead. I used the following P/Invoke signature for the CloseHandle which seems to work fine:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
```

The following must be added to the app.manifest as posted by Mas:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
<application>
  <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

    <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
    <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>

    <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
    <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

</application>
```

and lastly, this won't work (at least under Win 7) when launched from Visual Studio. The parent process must be started from Windows Explorer.

Comment: Andrew - thanks for the contribution.  I'm a bit removed from this problem so I can't validate, but it sounds like you know what you're talking about =)

Answer (score 4):

There is a post that uses apis that you are trying to use.
Perhaps you can get some insight from there.

[Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)

Comment: Strange.  I tried this, and I couldn't get it to work on 64-bit, just like all the other P/Invoke solutions for this.