# PDF IFilter Not Working On Server

Tags: pdf, ifilter

We are using IFilters to get the text content from PDFs and this is working fine locally but when we run the code on the server we are getting the following error:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
```

We are using searchFilterView (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_filter_view.html) and the same adobe IFilter is installed on the server (Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64bit) as is installed on my local machine (Windows 8.1 64bit) but it isn't working on the server.

Has anyone had any similar issues with the IFIlter (.pdf, AcroExch.Document.11, Adobe Acrobat Document, application/pdf) on Windows Server?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same problem. The PDF filter works on windows 7 but failed to load on windows server 2008. The solution is to assign the process running the PDF filter to a JobObject ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net)). In [this post](http://zabkat.com/blog/adobe-ifilter-exposed.htm) you can read about ADOBE dirty trick that causes this problem.