# Create a process and manage its cpu and memory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I want to write a winform program to create some processes(which is unmanaged c++ console program) as subprocess,because of there maybe more than one subprocesses created by the parent winform program, and someone need more CPU someone need more memory,I want to limit the subprocess's CPU and Memory. in order make the subprocess have an appropriate resources(CPU and memory) .

and if the parent winform is closed, all subprocess is running should be killed at the same time.

I have found a lot of article to introduce how to start a process using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) , but there is no one to introduce how to limit the subprocess CPU and Memory.

Update:I knew that system job object can be limited CPU and memory from @Blorgbeard's answer

I found some question about job objects with c# :

[Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed/4657392#4657392)

[Working example of CreateJobObject/SetInformationJobObject pinvoke in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net)

Comment: That's kind of the operating system's job.. You can't *limit* their CPU usage, although you *can* set their process CPU priority lower. You could monitor their memory usage, but what happens if they use "too much"? Kill the process? If you control the source for the subprocesses, it might be easier to just tell each process how much memory and cpu it should use.

Comment: Yeah ,I just want to tell each process how much maxmemory and maxcpu it can use. Is there a good example for c# to create operating system's job？

Comment: No, I mean, the operating system already manages all processes CPU and memory. If you control the source code for your sub processes, you can simply give them a config file, or a command-line option, that tells them how much memory and cpu to use.

Comment: Ok,Thanks.I manage the subprocess's code and I will try it.But I will search some details about system's job and how c# to create the job.

Comment: No, he means that you do not need to manage these. The operating system already does that.

Comment: yeah,thanks,I understand. Maybe the word **but** make the  ambiguity.I'm sorry for that. I just want to say I want to find another way that use system job in c#.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone is saying *you can't*. The OS determines CPU usage; you can't just "set the max". There *is* no max; only a priority. With memory, you can monitor it, but you can't restrict it from doing a `malloc`. Do you not understand what we are trying to say?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I got that 1. CPU usage can't limit just set a priority.2. I can't limit the memory .are all your means? I can't agree with your second opion.because (**A job can enforce limits such as working set size, process priority, and end-of-job time limit on each process that is associated with the job. If a process associated with a job attempts to increase its working set size or process priority from the limit established by the job... **)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx#job_limits_and_notifications]

Comment: You're working with processes, not jobs. And the job doesn't limit the amount of memory the process can use, it will simply kill the process once it passes the treshold. You can do this easily in C# as well, but *you're still killing the process*. You have the code for the subprocesses - so write them properly. Noöne from the outside can safely constrain the resources they'll be using. Even the OS has no other way than to kill the process when it consumes too much memory.