# Pinvoke CreateProcess input/output from file

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I use code from example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net). It works.

But I need to redirect standart input/output into files.
Process startup info struct has fields:

```
public IntPtr hStdInput;
public IntPtr hStdOutput;
public IntPtr hStdError;
```

I tried something like this:

```
StartupInfo startupInfo = new StartupInfo();
startupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf((object)startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = 128;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
startupInfo.hStdInput = fs.Handle;
```

And it does not work.

How can I pass file as standart input/output?

**UPD1**.

How do I call CreateProccess:

```
StartupInfo startupInfo = new StartupInfo();
startupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf((object)startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = 128;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
startupInfo.hStdInput = fs.Handle;

Pinvoke.SetErrorMode(ErrorModes.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | ErrorModes.SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT | ErrorModes.SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | ErrorModes.SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
CreationFlags dwCreationFlags = CreationFlags.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB | CreationFlags.CREATE_SUSPENDED | CreationFlags.CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM;
SecurityAttributes securityAttributes = new SecurityAttributes();
securityAttributes.bInheritHandle = 1;
ProcessInformation pi;

if (!Pinvoke.CreateProcess(null, configuration.RunString, ref securityAttributes, ref securityAttributes, boolInheritHandles: true, dwCreationFlags: dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment: IntPtr.Zero, lpszCurrentDir: configuration.Directory, startupInfo: ref startupInfo, pi: out pi))
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

**UPD2**.
I added `SetHandleInformation` call, but it does not help:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Pinvoke.SetHandleInformation(fs.Handle, 0x00000001, 0x00000001);
startupInfo.hStdInput = fs.Handle;
```

Comment: file handles must be *inheritable* and process must be created with *bInheritHandles == true*

Comment: @RbMm thank you for your comment. I added true in `CreateProcess` call and in `securityAttributes`, but it does not help

Comment: but you need use securityAttributes in create/open file handle - not process

Comment: `FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);` - this is `fs.Handle;` not inheritable handle

Comment: @RbMm ok, I see... It's difficult for me :) thank you for comments, I'll try!

Comment: You are going to need to create the file with CreateFile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan or use [`SetHandleInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724935.aspx) to turn on the `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` flag.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added this call, but it does not help. Maybe, I do something wrong

Comment: It's pointless to wrap the handle in a file stream. Not least because there is buffering at play. Call CreateFile. A classic mistake is to do this all from C# without having once learnt how to do it from C++ code. Easier to experiment in C++ code because all prototypes, constants etc. are available. Once you know how to do it, translate to pinvoke.

Comment: `#define STARTF_USESTDHANDLES 0x00000100` - this flag you must use in `STARTUPINFO` but you use `startupInfo.dwFlags = 128;` - `128==0x80!=0x100`

Comment: and better of course just create file as inheritable in single api call (via createfile) than do 2 system calls - first create file handle not inheritable and than change this

Comment: @RbMm yes, that's was is. You can turn this comment to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan @RbMm thank you both for help. I'm really bad at wiapi and C++, but your comments give me right direction for search. I'll try to do it as you described: work with files with `CreateFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments.

1. Set `startupInfo.dwFlags` to `0x00000100`
2. Add new function `CreateFile`:

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, DesiredAccess dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, ref SecurityAttributes lpSecurityAttributes, CreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
   ```
3. Create input/output handlers:

   ```
   var input = Pinvoke.CreateFile(inputFile, DesiredAccess.GENERIC_READ, 0, ref securityAttributes,
               CreationDisposition.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

   var output = Pinvoke.CreateFile(outputFile, DesiredAccess.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, ref securityAttributes,
                CreationDisposition.CREATE_NEW, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

   startupInfo.hStdInput = input;
   startupInfo.hStdOutput = output;

   ...

   public enum DesiredAccess : uint
   {
       GENERIC_WRITE = 30,
       GENERIC_READ = 31
   }

   public enum CreationDisposition : uint
   {
       CREATE_NEW = 1,
       CREATE_ALWAYS = 2,
       OPEN_EXISTING = 3,
       OPEN_ALWAYS = 4,
       TRUNCATE_EXISTING = 5
   }
   ```