# How to capture the process exit event of a Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'll use process events to wire up a method that will print something when the console is exited. You can see that because I don't know which event to wire up, I used three that all sound like they would work.

To test this, use the code below. The console window will stay open for 5 seconds. Click the "x" in the top right to close the window prior to the 5 seconds. Expected is that the CurrentDomain_ProcessExit method will be called. It doesn't get called. What is the correct way of doing this using managed .net code? I would rather not use p/invoke etc.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    currentProcess.Exited += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

internal static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("we just captured the process exit."); // <-- this is never reached.
}
```

Comment: What's the end goal here?  If you're able to catch this event, what are you wanting to do, and why?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not simple. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Console Application Exit Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event)

Comment: @Brendan: my parent console window spawns several other console applications (the children). When I kill the parent, I want the children to be killed, too. As far as I can tell there is no hierarchy or internal management to this, therefore I believe I need to kill the children in the above manner.

Comment: @muratgu: surely there must be an easy .Net, managed solution to this?

Comment: @ahmed: not a duplicate: that answer uses non-managed pinvoke style code; I want a managed .net solution.

Comment: @sapbucket: unfortunately no .net solution, since this is a "windows" issue. windows kills the process when you hit ctr-c or close the window. it's not going to let your .net code know before doing it.

Comment: @sapbucket AFAICT, there isn't one. Pinvoke is your only option (again, AFAIK) and there's nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: I would advise looking at the Job Object Windows API, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net). Yes you'll have to use P/Invoke but it is probably the only thing that is guaranteed to work for the scenario you describe, automatically shutting down child processes on any exit condition of the parent.

Comment: @everyone: I am surprised by how difficult this is! I will study your responses and perhaps revisit the pinvoke solutions. Moderator, please keep this open for a few days in case a solution appears from someone else. I don't want to completely shut the door on a .Net/managed solution.