# How to manage multiple processes in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console app that I need to manage multiple processes. By manage i mean that if one process exits that i want to start it up again. So basically my main process will run all the time and watch to see if process 1 or 2 exits and if so to start them again.

With following code the program just exits right away with 0 errors.

```
static void Main() {
    Task.Run(() => Process1());
    Task.Run(() => Process2());
}

private static void Process1() {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "a process 1 file path";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    try {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        Process1();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void Process2() {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "a process2 file path";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    try {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        Process2();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you've posted?

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias It just exits main program immediately

Comment: You could pinvoke and create them using windows jobs to do this, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net)

Comment: @nna12 I feel like i should be able to do it similarly to the way i have in my example. I am just missing something basic.

Comment: Why not just use something to wrap your exes up as devices then get the windows device manager to watch them and restart them. If you have the code for the exes you're going to watch, upgrade them to be services

Comment: @Caius Jard Services would have worked great. Not sure why i didn't think of that but i found a solution.  Putting together answer now.

Comment: Sorry, "devices" there (twice) was a typo of services - well done on decoding what my fat thumbs on a tiny iPhone keyboard meant there!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by removing the recursive calls, putting each method that managed a task into a infinite loop and then awaiting each task:

```
static void Main() {
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => Process1());
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => Process2());
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Comment: Waiting both tasks at once might be preferable: `Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);`

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias Updated code based on your suggestion. Much better

Comment: Not sure I get how this restarts a process when it stops. It looks like it just waits til both have stopped then quits

Comment: @Caius Jard In the Process method(s) i added infinite loop while(true). So if waitforexit finishes then loop starts over