# Shutting down sub-processes of a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a Windows Service, which starts a number of sub-processes, one of which having sub-processes of its own. When a normal shutdown occurs, the processes are being ordered to terminate. So far so good.
However, in the event of a crash, some of the sub-processes (or their sub-processes) are still running (or even stalled). Neither I as a user nor the new instance of the Windows service (with the same user (LocalSystem)) are allowed to terminate the old sub-processes, leaving no other option than a reboot.
Is there a reason MS stops me from shooting down those orphaned sub-processes? Is there a way around that?

I use C#'s Process.Kill() function to terminate processes. When I run the service in a dosbox, it of course works fine (running as my user).

Comment: It sounds like you want/need to be using [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects). I don't think there's a managed wrapper for those but there's an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6266820/15498) about using the API from C#.