# c# run .bat file application as administrator do not start

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, service

I have to run a .bat file from c#...
I use this method.

```html
 file = "C:\\Diego\\PublishCore\\Startup_service.bat";
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true; 
                psi.FileName = file;
                psi.UseShellExecute = true;
                psi.Verb = "runas";
                Process.Start(psi);
```

.BAT is executed... but the action I ask to perfom it does not execute...

If my  .bat says `MKDir MyDir`...  Its creates a Directory called `MyDIr` with no problems.

But when my bat says `dotnet myApp.dll`, a cmd Windows opens and closes, but it does not start myApp aplication....

If a doublé-click my .bat is runs fine.

What I am missing? Why the aplication does not start?

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321981/how-to-use-c-sharp-run-batch-file-as-administrator-to-install-windows-services#38322466

Comment: It has nothing to do my problem.. I am running as Administrador. My problem is that Windows opens a closes without executing it... Thanks

Comment: I would think it cannot find the location of your program because when you run a batch file as administrator, the working directory becomes SYSTEM32.

Comment: We can help you better troubleshoot your .bat script if you post the code for it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it...

The problem was that, as my bat run the instruction `dotnet myApp.dll`.
I set the path file where the file was, but it was executed in the location where the my Solution is, instead of running in the same directory where I have .bat file.

I have to set `WorkingDirectory` and `Arguments`

```html
 C:\\Diego\\PublishCore\\Startup_InomCore.bat
 
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Diego\\PublishCore";
                //   psi.CreateNoWindow = true; 
                psi.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
                psi.Arguments = "/c start /wait " + "C:\\Diego\\PublishCore\\Startup_InomCore.bat";
                //     psi.UseShellExecute = true;
                psi.Verb = "runas"; 
                var process = Process.Start(psi);
```